# Ruby array printing

Tags: ruby, xml, arrays, nokogiri

I have an array of objects ([nokogiri xml nodes](http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html)) and each node is having `name` and `value`.
I want to print them in the format `name=value` without iterating in for loop.

if I use arr * "," I'm able to see just the values as below

```
4900.00,5.00,0.00,-100.00,100.00
6085.00,5.00,1285.00,1185.00,100.00
6015.00,5.00,30.00,-70.00,100.00
5915.00,5.00,0.00,-100.00,100.00
5815.00,5.00,0.00,-100.00,100.00
```

Is there something that can be done here.

Comment: @LBg puts arr returns the values alone

Comment: Do you have some sample code to show what you are doing?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
array.each do |n|
  puts "#{n.name}=#{n.value}"
end
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing something similar, I guess I cant expect more from array without changing the to_s of the object in the array.

Comment: You can use `collect` to transform the array before displaying it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your Nokogiri nodes have `name` and `value` attributes (not child elements), here's one way:

```
# Convert the array into a new array of strings
namevals = my_array.map{ |node| "#{node['name']}=#{node['value']}" }

# See it with space delimiters
puts namevals.join(' ')
```

Possibly useful alternative:

```
# Create a hash mapping unique names to values
namevals = Hash[ my_array.map{ |node| [ node['name'], node['value'] } ]
```